# Como comparar dois arrays e retornar a diferença entre eles?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho 2 arrays que vem de 2 bancos diferentes, um vem do sql server outro do mysql.

a consulta do Mysl Retorna assim..

```
    array (size=6)
  0 => string 'ultimoteste3' (length=12)
  1 => string 'ultimoteste3' (length=12)
  2 => string 'Rodrigues' (length=9)
  3 => string 'ultimoteste3@hotmail.com' (length=24)
  4 => string '2' (length=1)
  5 => string 'Teste Curso' (length=11)
```

Já a consulta do sql server que é uma Procedure retorna assim:

```
 array (size=16)
  'username' => string 'username' (length=8)
  0 => string 'username' (length=8)
  'firstname' => string 'firstname' (length=9)
  1 => string 'firstname' (length=9)
  'lastname' => string 'lastname' (length=8)
  2 => string 'lastname' (length=8)
  'email' => string 'email' (length=5)
  3 => string 'email' (length=5)
  'lang' => string 'lang' (length=4)
  4 => string 'lang' (length=4)
  'course1' => string 'course1' (length=7)
  5 => string 'course1' (length=7)
  'type1' => string 'type1' (length=5)
  6 => string 'type1' (length=5)
  'auth' => string 'auth' (length=4)
  7 => string 'auth' (length=4)
```

Quanto uso

```
print_r(array_diff($lista1, $lista2));
```

o resultado vem assim...

```
Array ( )
```

Preciso percorrer os dois arrays e descobrir os usuários que estão em uma e não em outra, trazer a diferença entre os arrays...

para guardar os valores de cada um fiz assim

```
mysql = $lista1 = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

sqlServer = $lista2 = $consulta->fetchAll();  (pq uso PDO);
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? Especifique melhor, deixe mais claro em que quer ajuda.

Comment: Como vc armazena o resultado no $lista1 e $lista2?

Comment: Como você espera que retorna?

Comment: Espero que retorne os usuários diferentes entre os arrays, para formar outra lista de usuários, para assim eu manipular...

Comment: Este segundo array ($lista2) está com uma estrutura confusa, porque ele está com o índice diferente de $lista1?

Comment: Nossa! Você quer saber se o usuário é único?! Parece que está indo por um caminho difícil. Mas entendo, são dois bancos diferente.

Comment: realizei [o teste no ideone](http://ideone.com/yin9fi) apenas com os arrays e o resultado foi "normal", ele mostra todo o array 1 porque nenhum dado dele contem no array 2.

Comment: Certifique-se que a versão do PHP seja superior a 4.0.4, de acordo com a documentação a função array_diff tem problemas nas versões antigas.

Comment: Lembrando que o array_diff exibe os valores do array do primeiro parâmetro que NÃO estão no segundo parâmetro. E não o contrário.

Comment: Faz o seguinte troca os `var_dump()` por `var_export($var, true);` ai vc coloca a estruta pronto dos arrays de teste na pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa função faz um trabalho melhor, pois realiza uma operação XOR em ambos os arrays, a função nativa do PHP apenas verifica os valores do primeiro parâmetro que NÃO estão no segundo parâmetro:

```
function ary_diff( $ary_1, $ary_2 ) {
  // compare the value of 2 array
  // get differences that in ary_1 but not in ary_2
  // get difference that in ary_2 but not in ary_1
  // return the unique difference between value of 2 array
  $diff = array();

  // get differences that in ary_1 but not in ary_2
  foreach ( $ary_1 as $v1 ) {
    $flag = 0;
    foreach ( $ary_2 as $v2 ) {
      $flag |= ( $v1 == $v2 );
      if ( $flag ) break;
    }
    if ( !$flag ) array_push( $diff, $v1 );
  }

  // get difference that in ary_2 but not in ary_1
  foreach ( $ary_2 as $v2 ) {
    $flag = 0;
    foreach ( $ary_1 as $v1 ) {
      $flag |= ( $v1 == $v2 );
      if ( $flag ) break;
    }
    if ( !$flag && !in_array( $v2, $diff ) ) array_push( $diff, $v2 );
  }

  return $diff;
}
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#76391

Comment: Nao seria mais facil unir os dois e depois retornar os valores únicos (para não repetir)?

Comment: Walker, funcionou, porém está fazendo um MERGE, juntando as duas lista.

Comment: @YuriRodrigues Isso está acontecendo porque ambos os arrays são diferentes entre si. Você deve trabalhar na estrutura dos arrays para que eles tenham os mesmos índices.

Answer (score 2):

Se você deseja apenas retornar um `array` único, tanto com usuários que está com `array` como em outro, é mais fácil você unir os dois arrays e depois retornar os valores únicos da soma dois dois.

```
$allUsersDiff = array_unique(
    array_merge($lista1, $lista2)
);
```

Considere esse exemplo um exercício de fixação:

```
$array1 = array('wallace', 'wayne', 'marcos');

$array2 = array('cleber', 'wallace', 'junior');

var_dump(array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2)));
```

O resultado da união desses arrays, geram 6 items, porém 5 são retornados, pois valores duplicados são transformados em únicos.

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "wallace"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "wayne"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "marcos"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "cleber"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "junior"
}
```

[Teste no Ideone](https://ideone.com/260eus)